# Turning matrix into array of objects in javascript with underscore

Tags: arrays, underscore.js

I want to turn an array such as:

`[[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]`

into

`[{Duration: 0, Title: 0}, {Duration: 1, Title: 1}, {Duration: 2, Title: 2}]`

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
var a = [[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]];

_.map(a, function() {return {Duration: , Title: }   });
```

But I'm not able to reference the current value I'm looping at. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function is given a parameter, the current element (an array here):

```
_.map(a, function (data) {return {Duration: data[0], Title: data[1]} });
```

**Update: to make dynamic keys**

You could do this using the underscore function `each`,  though I'm not really familiar with underscore:

```
var keys = ['Duration', 'Title'],
    res;

res = _.map(a, function (data, dataIndex) {
    var hashMap = {};

    _.each(keys, function (key, keyIndex) {
        hashMap[key] = data[keyIndex];
    });

    return hashMap;
});
```

Comment: What if I had an array of values like ['Duration', 'Title', 'etc'], so that I need to set the object values dynamically? Should I place another map within this map? Thanks and I will check this when the time ends.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore's [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) function takes an array and returns a new array.  You can map it how you want.

```
var a = [[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]];
var b = _.map(a, function(row) {
  return { "Duration" : row[0], "Title" : row[1] };
})
```

If you want to do the fields dynamically, you could do this!  Javascript is fun.

```
var a = [[0,0,4], [1, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6]];
var fields = ["Duration","Title","other"];
var b = _.map(a, function(row) {
  return _.object(fields, row);
})
```

Here is a **[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGKv2D?p=preview)** you can fork to experiment for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it! I will read the code carefully. I upvoted you but will check aduch since he technically answered the question first.